# Implementation of a linear congruential generator

Tags: c++, random

Here's a simple LCG that I've made to learn a bit more about pseudo random number generation.

Is this implementation correct, and if so, how can I improve it further?

The following code is self contained and it should run without problems.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

namespace Random {
    class LCG {
        static constexpr uint64_t const A = 0x5851F42D4C957F2D;
        static constexpr uint64_t const C = 0x14057B7EF767814F;
        static constexpr uint64_t const M = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;

        uint64_t this_seed;

        auto now() noexcept {
            using namespace std::chrono;
            auto const output = high_resolution_clock::now();
            return output.time_since_epoch().count();
        }

    public:
        LCG() noexcept
            : this_seed(now()) {
        }

        LCG(uint64_t const value) noexcept
            : this_seed(value) {
        }

        void seed() noexcept {
            this_seed = now();
        }

        void seed(uint64_t const value) noexcept {
            this_seed = value;
        }

        // [0, 2 ^ 64 - 1)
        auto next() noexcept {
            this_seed = (this_seed * A + C) & M;
            return this_seed;
        }

        void discard(uint64_t const amount) noexcept {
            for (uint64_t i = 0; i != amount; ++i) {
                next();
            }
        }

        // [0, 1)
        double get() noexcept {
            return static_cast<double>(next()) / M;
        }

        // x - 0 == (-1 | 0 | 1) ? 0 : x > 0 ? [0, x) : (x, 0]
        int64_t get(int64_t const x) noexcept {
            return static_cast<int64_t>(get() * x);
        }

        // b - a == (-1 | 0 | 1) ? 0 : b > a ? [a, b) : (b, a]
        int64_t get(int64_t const a, int64_t const b) noexcept {
            return a + static_cast<int64_t>(get() * (b - a));
        }
    };
}

int main() {

    Random::LCG lcg(0);
    std::map<int64_t, uint64_t> buckets;
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i != 1000000; ++i) {
        ++buckets[lcg.get(10)];
    }
    for (auto const [a, b] : buckets) {
        std::cout << a << '\t' << b << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's self contained. It's also filled with magic numbers and oddly named variables making it hard to see what you're doing and why. An explanation would greatly improve this question.

Comment: Your code looks an awful lot like [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/WdxTEzby). Did you write this yourself?

Comment: @Mast it's an [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), and those names (`A` as multiplier, `C` as constant offset and `M` as modulus) are common with LCGs. I'd expect them the follow the Hull-Dobell requirements (see \$c \neq 0\$ in the article).

Comment: @Mast, I did write it myself. As far as I know, I'm the only one that prefixes the private member variables with `this_`. Also, some of the comments from that paste bin are missing.

Comment: With something like a LCG, which is a common library function, you can learn a lot by looking at source libraries.  The C, C++ and Java libraries are certainly available and I presume others.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2):

Your mask value `M` is gaining you nothing, since the types for `this_seed` and `M` are the same and you have every bit in `M` set to 1.  Your comment for `next` is wrong; it can return 2<sup>64</sup>-1 (i.e., all bits set).  The correct range can be stated as either `[0, 2 ^ 64 - 1]` or `[0, 2 ^ 64)`.  This in turn can cause your `get` functions to return a value larger than expected (1.0, `x`, or `b`).

Where did you get the values for the `A` and `B` constants?  I've not looked to see if they are appropriate.

Comment: The constants `A`, `C` and `M` are from `MMIX by Donald Knuth`. As for the `get` methods, they've always yielded values between the range specified in the comments. As for the `next` method comment, I wasn't sure... what would be the correct range? `[0, 2 ^ 64 - 1]`?

Comment: I took the `M` value from here `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use`. On the table it says, `2 ^ 64`, but because that number will overflow in C++, I've used `2 ^ 64 - 1`, but you're right, I've just tested the code and neither `&` nor `%`  works, they just yield the same value.

Comment: @JoãoPires I've updated the answer with the proper range for `next`.  Using numbers from _MMIX_ is good.

Comment: What about  the `&` and the `M` value, how can I correct it?

Answer (score 2):

> `this_seed = (this_seed * A + C) & M;`

should just read

```
this_seed = this_seed * A + C;
```

The modulo is done free for you - unsigned arithmetic in a 64-bit word.
You do not need `M`

For the double function `[0.0,1.0)` this gives a uniform distribution:

```
return static_cast<double>(next() >> 11) * (1.0 / (UINT64_C(1) << 53));
```

The less random low order bits are discarded.
The multiplier compiles to 0x1p-53

Comment: I've tried improving the `double get()` with your code, but it messes up the other two `get` methods. How do I fix them? There's plenty of tutorials on how to implemente a RNG, but they all skip the `How do I get a number between a and b from that?`.

Comment: My bad, I wrote `next() >> 1` instead of `next() >> 11`. It is working now. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `now` function doesn’t have anything to do with the class; it is just a helper.  So make it `static`.

```
void seed(uint64_t const value)
```

The `const` is OK, but you are not doing that consistently.  The constructor with the same kind of argument does not have `const`.

Comment: In the new improved version, the `now` function was made static. Both the constructor and the seed method has the parameter `value` marked as `const`, in fact, all my parameters are marked as `const`.